# .htaccess rewrite with dots

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm looking for a way to do something like this in .htaccess:

```
This.is.my-website.com
```

Please note: `This.is` is the rewrite to the directory `This.is` and `mywebsite.com` is the URL of the site. I want all requests to the site to be redirected to that folder (`301`?). Is it possible to achieve this in .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.my-website.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

for an internal rewrite (won't change the URL in browser's address bar).

Or to externally redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.my-website.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-website.com/%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Any more advice? Where should the .htaccess file containing the code be? What parts should I change?

Comment: @Charlie in the htaccess file in your document root. Change "my-website.com" to whatever your website is

Comment: @Charlie it looks like you're asking for the other way around: *I want all requests to the site (`This.is.my-website.com`) to be redirected to that folder (`This.is`)*. So what do you want?